# how to display result from CURL API Wordpress in controller in CodeIgniter view

Tags: wordpress, api, codeigniter

I want to retrieve some data from wordpress via this link

> https://domain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

I have created a function in the controller like this and it runs fine when I do the `var_dump` command

```
$url = 'https://sumbermulyo-jombang.desa.id/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$hasil = json_decode($response);
$data['posts'] = $hasil;
//var_dump(json_decode($response, true)); 

$this->load->view('layouts/dashboard/header');
$this->load->view('layouts/dashboard/sidebar');
$this->load->view('pages/dashboard/home',$data);
$this->load->view('layouts/dashboard/footer');
```

the problem is that I still don't really understand how to display the result of the controller to the CodeIgniter view, when I do a foreach in the view like this

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?=$post['id']?></td>
  <td><?=$post['title']?></td>
  <td><?=$post['link']?></td>
 </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

if there is a mistake in the case I ask here or there is a part that is not clear, let me correct it and explain it, thanks for the assistance

> edit

the real problem is that it turns out that the generated JSON is a nested JSON, so I'll answer my own question because I've got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution i got few days ago

```
<?php
 $array = 0; 
 foreach($posts as $post) : 
?>
                           
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $posts[$array]['id'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo '<img src='.$posts[$array]['better_featured_image']['media_details']['sizes']['medium']['source_url'];'/>'?> </td>
 <td><?php echo $posts[$array]['title']['rendered'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $posts[$array]['content']['rendered'];?></td>
 <td><a href="<?php echo $posts[$array]['link'];?>">Link</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
 $array++; 
 endforeach;
?>
```

at first I didn't realize and still not familiar with how to call and write the result of nested JSON

Answer (score 0):

**Try With This**

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?=$post->id;?></td>
  <td><?=$post->title;?></td>
  <td><?=$post->link;?></td>
 </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

If the result in array of object,you will change the $post['id'] to $post->id.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: previously I also tried it like that but it still doesn't work, thanks for the assistance :")